# python3 : append string to every list

Tags: python-3.x

I am using python3 with gitpython and  generating the result as shown below :

> 0bf35c4cf243e0fe13adbe7aeba99a03ddf6acfd  refs/release/17.xp.0.95/head
> d0c5f748e65488ce2e90c1ed027c2da252a5c6a2  refs/release/17.xp.0.96/head
> 530bdbf8f06859d8aca55cee7b57e27e68e87a94  refs/release/17.xp.0.97/head
> 0dd0342466540bc38e26ef74af6c8837d165cae5  refs/release/17.xp.0.98/head
> 919b78fb737b00830a8e48353b0f977c442600dd  refs/release/17.xp.0.99/head

But i want to append the string name "acme" to every line, for example

> 0bf35c4cf243e0fe13adbe7aeba99a03ddf6acfd  refs/release/17.xp.0.95/head
> acme
> d0c5f748e65488ce2e90c1ed027c2da252a5c6a2  refs/release/17.xp.0.96/head
> acme
> 530bdbf8f06859d8aca55cee7b57e27e68e87a94  refs/release/17.xp.0.97/head
> acme
> 0dd0342466540bc38e26ef74af6c8837d165cae5  refs/release/17.xp.0.98/head
> acme
> 919b78fb737b00830a8e48353b0f977c442600dd  refs/release/17.xp.0.99/head
> acme

Below is the code i am using, please advise the solution to append/concatenate the string to every end of the lines.

```
import os,re,sys,argparse
import git


if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage : --track <track name> without "track/" ')
    sys.exit()

input_track = sys.argv[1].strip()
print ("Checking for the track name - track/",input_track)



def show_ref(input_track,gitname):
    url = "git@github/"+gitname+".git"
    g = git.cmd.Git()
    ig1 = g.ls_remote(url,"refs/heads/track/"+input_track).split('\d')
    print ("Branch for glide-test:\n",'\n'.join(ig1))
    for x in range(13,20):
        ig6 = g.ls_remote(url,"refs/release/"+str(x)+"."+input_track+".*/head").split('|')
        print ('\n'.join(ig6))
        #"\n".join(map(lambda word: word+"x", s.split("\n")))


show_ref(input_track,"acme")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply modify this line

```
ig6 = g.ls_remote(url,"refs/release/"+str(x)+"."+input_track+".*/head").split('|')
```

By adding the string "acme" to the string you build.

Like this

```
ig6 = g.ls_remote(url,"refs/release/"+str(x)+"."+input_track+".*/head acme").split('|')
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: No , this is not, appending "acme" will add to git ls-remote command meant to retrieve the SHA of a git repo and branch. Adding the string "ACME" will lead to no data return.

Comment: Oh sure, I see what you mean. But can't you do the same thing one line below and add it to the print statement? If you only want to print it that is and not add it to the string itself.

Comment: We want on every end of the line, we have a requirement to parse the lines.

Comment: I find it a little hard to understand your question: do you want a list of these strings, so that you can parse it afterwards? At the moment you're only printing them. So I would say you could simply append each new line to a list and then add  your "acme" string to the entries.